# Java Collections Sort not accepting comparator constructor with arg

Tags: java, sorting, collections, comparator

I'm getting a compiler error for this line:

`Collections.sort(terms, new QuerySorter_TFmaxIDF(myInteger));`

My customized Comparator is pretty basic; here's the signature and constructor:

```
public class QuerySorter_TFmaxIDF implements Comparator<Term>{  
private int numberOfDocs;
QuerySorter_TFmaxIDF(int n){
    super();
    numberOfDocs = n;
}
```

}

Is there an error because I'm passing an argument into the Comparator? I need to pass an argument...

Comment: the constructor argument shouldn't matter. what's the error you're getting and what is the definition of the variable `terms`?

Comment: "I'm getting a compiler error" -- WHAT is the error? How can you say something like that and leave it out? Please help us help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies with your comparator.  It's for sorting Term-s but the array you're handing it via the Collections.sort() method has elements of type String.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason you can't pass an argument to that constructor. Your code is missing:

1. The superclass. Your constructor calls `super()` so I *assume* there is one; and
2. The `compare()` method required by the `Comparator` interface.

What exactly is `numberOfDocs` meant to do here?

Comment: @cletus compare() is implemented, but it is too large to post in this comment. you're right, i don't need the super() call, but i'm still getting the same error without that line. numberOfDocs is used in the compare() method for a calculation

@oedo the error is:

cannot find symbol
method sort (Java.util.ArrayList<java.Lang.String>, projectPackage.QuerySorter_TFmaxIDF)

Answer (score 1):

Your Comparator needs to compare Strings because your ArrayList contains Strings.

```
public class QuerySorter_TFmaxIDF implements Comparator<Term> {
```

has to be

```
public class QuerySorter_TFmaxIDF implements Comparator<String> {
```